# Heartrate with no decimal places

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, healthkit

Im doing a watch app for the Apple Watch in Xcode and the sample code from the Apple Developer site [SpeedySloth: Creating a Workout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/speedysloth_creating_a_workout) has the HeartRate rounded to one decimal place, e.g. 61.0
How can I fix this?

```
case HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate):
                /// - Tag: SetLabel
                let heartRateUnit = HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute())
                let value = statistics.mostRecentQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)
                let roundedValue = Double( round( 1 * value! ) / 1 )
                label.setText("\(roundedValue) BPM")
```

I tried changing both the 1's in there to 0 but that gave me a 6.1 BPM or a 0.0 BPM

Thanks

Comment: You’re trying to make a string. Use a NumberFormatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to round to an integer and show the integer.

```
let value = // ... some Double ...
let s = String(Int(value.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)))
label.setText(s + " BPM")
```

Properly, however, you should put formatting a string based on a number into the hands of a NumberFormatter. That's its job: to *format* a *number*.

```
let i = value.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .none
let s = nf.string(from: i as NSNumber)!
// ... and now show the string
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this and it worked. Im probably adding stuff I shouldn't but its working
                `let heartRateUnit = HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute())
                let value = statistics.mostRecentQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)
                let roundedValue = Double( round( 1 * value! ) / 1 )
                let valueA = roundedValue
                let s = String(Int(valueA.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)))
                label.setText(s + " BPM")`